# Typhoon DI on storyboard integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, typhoon

I'm new to **Typhoon**. I'm reading documentation to inject dependencies into my storyboard's view controllers. I have basic understand of how the framework does the DI on classes, but storyboards seems complicated. I have read both [storyboards](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Storyboards) and [PList integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Plist-Integration) documentation but I'm kind of confused.

1. This may sound silly and obvious. If my storyboard filename is `Main.storyboard`, in my `plist` I'd add key `UILaunchStoryboardName` with value `Main.storyboard`?
2. What would be the value for key `UIMainStoryboardFile`?
3. Do dependencies get injected automatically or how do I specify which dependencies get injected into each of my storyboard's view controllers?

I was unable to find an example or tutorial that uses storyboard (and since most of them are in **objc** and I'm working with **Swift**, it's kinda hard to follow up every step, so I apologize in advance if these questions are silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer questions one and two, if you create a project from Xcode specifying to use storyboards, then those values will already be completed in your plist. If you have a legacy project, this is a nice way to see what those values should be.

As for question 3, if you 'annotate' your storyboard view controllers with auto-injection macros, then dependencies are indeed injected automatically. For non-storyboard view controllers then to have dependencies injected, an instance should be obtained from Typhoon, just like in the [Quick Start](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Quick-Start).

Note that you can inject the assembly itself into a view controller, in order to load an injected object graph 'on demand'.

Comment: When you say 'annotate' you mean the runtime argument **typhoonKey**?

Comment: I mean to apply the auto-injection macros (https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Auto-injection-%28Objective-C%29) or alternatively you can use injection methods in your assembly.